# Production of CTAB

Tags: organic-chemistry

I'm looking for the method/recipe/procedure for producing cetyltrimethylammonium bromide (CTAB). I didn't see it in Ullmann's, and I can't seem to find it online. Does anyone have a reference?

Comment: You should be able to find this on Reaxys/SciFinder, but looking at the structure it seems like the most obvious way would be to take the parent amine and quaternise it with MeBr (complicated by the fact that MeBr is basically a gas).

Answer (score 1):

The following is what i consider to be the best/easiest preparation taken from here: Scheraga; Backus - Journal of the American Chemical Society, 1951, vol. 73, p. 5108

To the cetyl bromide was added a 30% excess of a 25%
solution of trimethylamine in methanol. The mixture was
refluxed on a steam-bath for one hour using a condenser
cooled with ice-water. The resultant solid was recrystallized
three times by dissolving in warm methanol and recovering
by an ether precipitation with cooling in an ice-bath. The
detergent was dried in a vacuum desiccator.

However, if this is for lab use (and not for literature review or relevant) i recommend to buy it since it costs only 15.8 £/100 g on Alfa-Aesar while the bromide itself is already at 14.7 £/100 g.

Answer (score -1):

This article (Journal of Radiolabelled Compounds **33** (1993) 33 )  describes the synthesis of 14C labelled CTAB which should offer you a usable procedure